# Symfony2 + FOS Rest Bundle - Regular route

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am developing an application using Symfony2 with fos-restbundle. I would like to create some API routes and also some regular routes (exactly one for AngularJS front-end). This is my fos_rest configuration (and a few configuration lines from sensio):

`sensio_framework_extra:
    view: { annotations: false }
    router: { annotations: true }
    request: { converters: true }
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: true
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    body_listener: true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json', 'xml'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true`

As you can see i have **view_response_listener** enabled and **view annotations** disabled. I can't find the way to define "regular" (not REST) route (and view) for index action (neccesary for AngularJS). Keep getting an error:

```
ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotAcceptableHttpException: "No matching accepted Response format could be determined" at C:\wamp\www\CRMProject\vendor\friendsofsymfony\rest-bundle\EventListener\FormatListener.php line 69
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add additional rule for your index page(for example):

```
format_listener:
    rules:
        - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json', 'xml'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
        - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'text/html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
```

Read docs about format listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/format_listener.html

Comment: Working! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have another problem connected with previous one. There are many errors like this: "NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable - http://crmproject.localhost/bundles/app/css/crm.css". I can't load any JS/CSS. Same reason as in main question, but same solution doesn't help.

Comment: I've tried such solution, but still getting that error. I've also changed "fallback_format" to null following to docs, but no results. Still getting "The server returned a "406 Not Acceptable". It's weird, because request's headers from Fiddler looks fine:
_Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate_

Comment: Thats strange because my server(nginx + php5fpm ) is serving this right and I get 200 on assets.

Comment: I had the same issue with Symfony 4.3.3 and it worked. Here is actual doc link: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/format_listener.html

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/format_listener.html) you can also disable the format listener for the "normal" part of the site (not the APIs):

> Often when integrating this Bundle with existing applications, it
>   might be useful to disable the format listener for some routes. In
>   this case it is possible to define a rule that will stop the format
>   listener from determining a format by setting stop to true as a rule
>   option. Any rule containing this setting and any rule following will
>   not be considered and the Request format will remain unchanged.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json', 'xml'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true } # Available for version >= 1.5
```